# Filtering ajax content with jscroll

Tags: jquery-jscroll

I am using bootstrap filters and I load the whole ajax response to a div.It contains the link to the next page for jscroll.However its not working it does not  load.When I first enter my page it works perfectly.

Comment: I do not understand where the problem might be can someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution after the Ajax has finished set jscroll data tou null,  $(container). data('jscroll', null) it should work perfectly. After that you call jscroll again with your parameters.